# Visual Studio Code doesn't find my python file. [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling with a Visual Studio Code python compiler. Whenever I try to run the code it says

```
python: can't open file 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\Programowasko\Python\Cybepunk encounter 
    calculator\cyberpunk.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The only code which is written there is `print("Hello World")` by now. Also any other code which has recently worked, now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code, when we use the command "python file.py" to run a python file in its internal terminal, it requires us to go to the parent folder of the executable file: ( Please check the spelling of the file and folder names. )

[image]

In addition, we usually use the run button provided by the "python" extension in VS Code, which will automatically execute the run command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a file directory without spaces? e.g. `Cybepunk_encounter_calculator` or even enclosing in double quotes `""` like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530578/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-folder-with-space-in-its-name)

Comment: Yeah, already tried that. Also other files are in folders with spaces in it and they did worked

Answer (score 0):

error is due to space.
Maybe following can help you

```
python "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Programowasko\Python\Cybepunk encounter calculator\cyberpunk.py"
```

Comment: i'm sorry, what has changed? I can't see the difference

Comment: The shell has a feature called wordsplitting that makes each word in your command invocation a separate word, or arg. To pass path to Python as a single word with spaces in it, you must have to added "".